# Using @PageActivationContext without Hibernate

Tags: java, tapestry

Is there some trick to using @PageActivationContext without Hibernate in Tapestry? I've got the following page:

```
public class DisplayTopic {
    @PageActivationContext
    private Topic topic;
}
```

This in my AppModule class:

```
@Contribute(ValueEncoderSource.class)
public static void contributeValueEncoderSource(MappedConfiguration<Class<Topic>, ValueEncoderFactory<Topic>> configuration) {
    configuration.addInstance(Topic.class, TopicEncoder.class);
}
```

And finally this as my TopicEncoder:

```
public class TopicEncoder implements ValueEncoder<Topic>, ValueEncoderFactory<Topic> {

    @Override
    public String toClient(Topic value) {
        return value.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Topic toValue(String clientValue) {
        return Start.data.getLocator().getTopicById(clientValue);
    }

    @Override
    public ValueEncoder<Topic> create(Class<Topic> type) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get the following exception:

```
Exception in method null, parameter #1: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.util.UnknownValueException: Could not find a coercion from type java.lang.String to type Main.Topic.
```

I've been through the documentation several times, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try contributing to `TypeCoercer` to convert a `Str` to `Topic`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but I can not! It works for me. What version of Tapestry5 are you using? Can you post the implementation of Topic? It loooks like Topic is a subclass of Main. Have you tried moving Topic into its own java file?

Answer (score 0):

What you've done looks like it should work to me. I'm taking a total guess here... but are you using either tapestry-cometd or tapestry-atmosphere?

This issue affects both https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-cometd/issues/62

The issue is fixed in the latest tapestry-cometd, it has not been fixed in tapestry-atmosphere.